# OAuth/Twitteroauth library and Authorization headers

Tags: php, curl, oauth, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am trying to better understand OAuth by experimenting with the [twitteroauth](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth) php library.

It is my understanding that the way to authenticate over OAuth is to make use of an 'Authorize' header when using cUrl. However, examining the source for the twitteroauth library, I can see that the header is set as so for post requests:

```
 curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Expect:'));
```

And the parameters that should be set in the 'Authorize' header are actually being set in the post body instead in the line:

```
 curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
```

What is the reason for it being done this way? When in the twitter API guidelines is specifies the following implementation for the header:

```
POST /1/statuses/update.json?include_entities=true HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Connection: close
User-Agent: OAuth gem v0.4.4
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Authorization: 
        OAuth oauth_consumer_key="xvz1evFS4wEEPTGEFPHBog", 
              oauth_nonce="kYjzVBB8Y0ZFabxSWbWovY3uYSQ2pTgmZeNu2VS4cg", 
              oauth_signature="tnnArxj06cWHq44gCs1OSKk%2FjLY%3D", 
              oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", 
              oauth_timestamp="1318622958", 
              oauth_token="370773112-GmHxMAgYyLbNEtIKZeRNFsMKPR9EyMZeS9weJAEb", 
              oauth_version="1.0"
Content-Length: 76
Host: api.twitter.com

status=Hello%20Ladies%20%2b%20Gentlemen%2c%20a%20signed%20OAuth%20request%21
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A client may add the HTTP Expect header to tell the server "hey, I expect you to behave in a certain way". For some reason, Twitter's implementation wants you to expect nothing. I ran into this with my own home-grown implementation. I'm not sure why Twitter wants this header.

You may present your credentials and signature in the POST variables, or in the header. Both will work as long as the correct variables are set (oauth_consumer_key, oauth_nonce, oauth_signature, oauth_signature_method, oauth_timestamp, and oauth_token).

I find setting the Authorization header to be cleaner because it does not depend upon the request method (GET, POST, PUT, etc). But Twitter handles both cases perfectly fine. If that's  how they implemented it in their library, so be it.